# How to create UILabel inside UITextView in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uitextview

I want to add multiple skills in textfield like gmail app. When return keyboard then create new `UILabel` and when backspace then delete `UILabel`. Actually I want to add multiple skills so I can use add button and go to next view and add there but I want like gmail app[image]

Comment: You can check out `JSTokenField` or `TITokenField`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using one of the superb libraries out there ? This behaviour was implemented many times already.

For example have a look at this one:
[THContactPicker](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/THContactPicker/tree/master/Classes)

It uses UIView and UITextField subclass to manage this task and you get a bunch of useful delegate methods.